# Complex query in a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with a Many to Many relationship:

```
TABLE USER(id, name, ...)
TABLE GROUP(id, name, ...)
TABLE USER_GROUP(user_id, group_id)
```

Given a list of usernames, I want my backend to send an SQL query to the database.

This query must **select all groups (from table `GROUP`) which contain at least all users (from table `USER`) specified in the input list**.

Please note that the input list contains the usernames and not the user ids.

Requirements:

- I would like to avoid stored procedures and database side scripting if at all possible
- The input list must be a list of names and not a list of user ids

**Expected results:**

| Input list (usernames) | Expected result (groups) |
| --- | --- |
| `John`, `Celia` | `Group A`, `Group C` |
| `John`, `Jack`, `Celia` | `Group A` |
| `Jack` | `Group A`, `Group B` |

**Data :**

Table USER

```
+------+-------------------+
| ID   | NAME              |
+------+-------------------+
| 1    | John              |
| 2    | Jack              |
| 3    | Celia             |
| 4    | Alice             |
+------+-------------------+
```

Table GROUP

```
+------+-------------------+
| ID   | NAME              |
+------+-------------------+
| 1    | Group A           |
| 3    | Group B           |
| 4    | Group C           |
| 5    | Group D           |
+------+-------------------+
```

Table USER_GROUP

```
+-----------+-------------------+
| GROUP_ID  | USER_ID           |
+-----------+-------------------+
| 1         | 1                 |
| 1         | 2                 |
| 1         | 3                 |
| 2         | 1                 |
| 2         | 2                 |
| 3         | 1                 |
| 3         | 3                 |
| 3         | 4                 |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

EDIT:

I use PostgreSQL as my RDBMS

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I use PostgreSQL as my RDBMS. I edited my question with this information.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: Your groups are wrong if the expected results are correct.  You are missing group "2" for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that you are passing the values in as an array.  You can use:

```
select g.name
from groups g join
     user_groups ug
     on ug.group_id = g.id join
     users u
     on ug.user_id = u.id
where u.name = any (:input_list)
group by g.name
having count(*) = cardinality(:input_list);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8ada155297aa8ef34aa97d668f35d45d) is a db<>fiddle, with the data fixed to match the results you have in the question.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Users (User_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(255));
> CREATE TABLE Groups (Group_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(255));
> CREATE TABLE User_Group (User_ID INT , Group_ID INT);
> INSERT INTO Users (User_ID,Name) VALUES (1,'John'),(3,'Celia');
> INSERT INTO Groups (Group_ID,Name) VALUES(1,'Group A'),(4,'Group C');
> INSERT INTO User_Group(User_ID, Group_ID) VALUES(1,1),(3,4);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT  string_agg(U.Name::text, ',') AS UserNames
> ,string_agg(G.Name::text, ',') AS GroupNames FROM User_Group AS UG
> INNER JOIN Users AS U ON U.User_ID=UG.User_ID
> INNER JOIN Groups AS G ON G.Group_ID=UG.Group_ID
> WHERE U.Name IN ('John','Celia')
> ```
>
> ```
> usernames  | groupnames     
> :--------- | :--------------
> John,Celia | Group A,Group C
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c4543cc2c686210525ad81e20dbca3fa)*